# Javascript ENUM pattern naming convention

Tags: javascript, naming-conventions, jshint

I am working on a javascript project which requires use of javascript "Enums" meaning Objects like:

```
var WinnerEnum = {
    Player1: 1,
    Player2: 2,
    Draw: 0
};
```

This is working great for me, however, I have no idea what is the proper way (according to convention) to name the Enum because as far as I know only class names start with a capital letter (indicating the ability to call a constructor on).

JSHint also outputs the following warning:

```
Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor.
```

If there is no convention, I would appreciate a good way to name enums that would not confuse them with class names. **Update 2014** : JSHint no longer does this.

Comment: The way you've declared looks fine imo. Also, where is `new` required in the above scenario?

Comment: new is not required, it is convention that variable names only start with capital letters if they are functions and constructors.

Comment: @Benjamin: On which line of your code does that warning appear? You don't try to invoke `WinnerEnum`, do you?

Comment: yeah, but in this case it is neither. Its just a plain JS object. So new is totally not needed. I think your code is perfect as it is.

Comment: @techfoobar I know my code works and new is not needed, please read the question carefully (the warning originated in JSHint).

Comment: @Bergi I did not invoke WinnerEnum, I just looked at the value of  WinnerEnum.Player1

Comment: What i meant was that JSHint got it wrong. You need not change your code just bcoz some tool finds something wrong in it. Your code is good as it is.

Comment: `const` should be used when declaring a JS "Enum".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Google's coding conventions this is the correct way indeed to name an enum in javascript.

As requested [here is a link](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Naming#Naming).

Comment: Maybe opening an issue on JSHint github would be nice!

Comment: According to Google's coding conventions this is _not_ the correct way to name an enum, since the enum values should be ALL_CAPS, not UpperCamelCase. A relevant example in the Google JavaScript style guide you linked to is: `some.long.namespace.Fruit = {` `APPLE: 'a',` `BANANA: 'b'` `};`

Comment: @dharcourt, Unfortunately, Google's documentation is self-contradictory. They say, "EnumNamesLikeThis", but then provide the example you quoted. I prefer all caps (convention from a long time ago), but the Google docs just confuse users.

Comment: @squidbe I disagree- the guidelines say enums should be *named* in camelcase, but its properties are constants and, per their convention, are all-caps in the example.

Comment: @squibde Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my previous comment: According to Google's coding conventions and general JavaScript usage, enum names should indeed be UpperCamelCase (like WinnerEnum). It's the enum values that should be ALL_CAPS (like PLAYER_1, PLAYER_2, DRAW). Google's coding conventions are consistent in this regard, as are other more authoritative references and common usage. I'll provide a separate answer that is clearer in this regard.

Comment: You should include examples.

Comment: Adding this newer Google JS styleguide reference for clarify: https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming-enum-names

Answer (score 58):

That is indeed the correct way to name the enum, but the enum values should be ALL_CAPS instead of UpperCamelCase, like this:

```
var WinnerEnum = {
    PLAYER_1: 1,
    PLAYER_2: 2,
    DRAW: 0
};
```

This is similar to [Java's naming convention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) for enums.

Some references:

- [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-objects-enums)
- [Stijn de Witt's Blog](https://stijndewitt.com/2014/01/26/enums-in-javascript/)
- [Enumify documentation](http://2ality.com/2016/01/enumify.html)

As with coding style in general, you'll find people doing things in many different ways, with each way having its own set of good reason. To make things easiest for anyone reading and working with your code, however, I would recommend using the style which has the most authoritative reference and therefore usually the most widespread adoption.

I couldn't find any reference more authoritative than Google's style guide and the writings above, written by people who have given some serious thought to enums, but I'd be interested to hear of any better references.

Comment: TypeScript enums uses PascalCase for the enum name and enum-members. Maybe it comes from C# (both developed by Microsoft). But anyway... You should not mix languages. Just because Java uses UPPER_CASE does not mean that this also applies to other languages.

Comment: Also, we should not mix JS with TS. TS is defined by Microsoft, JS is defined by ECMA and community.

Comment: As pointed out by @Dominik this answer is incorrect. One can even see that the _de facto_ standard [is also PascalCase](https://grep.app/search?q=export%20enum&filter[lang][0]=TypeScript).

Comment: Stronger argument: ECMAScript and various Web APIs themselves use ALL_CAPS as enum keys: `Number.EPSILON`, `Math.SQRT2`, `Node.ELEMENT_NODE`, `Event.BUBBLING_PHASE`, `NodeFilter.SHOW_ALL`, `XMLHttpRequest.DONE`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon it does sound like a strong argument... However these examples are not enums.

Comment: @Ricardo Counter, counter argument—`GLenum`'s convention is UPPER_CASE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Constants

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no "correct" way* of declaring a pseudo-enum in JS. You should strive to be consistent within your existing code base and/or your organization's conventions if possible.

One popular convention is [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-objects-enums). E.g.:

```js
const TemperatureScale = {
  CELSIUS: 'celsius',
  FAHRENHEIT: 'fahrenheit',
};
```

---

Curiously, this is inconsistent with MDN's [hidden convention](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#examples) for `const`, as in Google's example, `TemperatureScale` is a `const` and `TemperatureScale.CELSIUS` is not!

* it must be a valid JavaScript identifier.

Comment: You can just [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) your object if by any means you can't trust your codebase not to reassign any of its internal values. This happens because `const` forbids reassignments - by overwriting an object's properties, you don't reassign the var name, as it's still pointing to the same object (see [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#:~:text=but%20if%20a%20constant%20is%20an%20object,.)).

Comment: If one gets to this point, however, maybe they should consider adding TypeScript to their project, if consistency is of such importance. (Sorry for the separate comment, I couldn't fit it there due to the huge links)

Comment: Also uppercasing is not really a "hidden" convention, nor is it directly _endorsed_ by MDN. It's stated as a _common_ convention - which is precisely what it is. Traditionally in programming (and in several languages still going strong today) it was convention to just name constants with CONSTANT_CASE (hence the name). You can even find examples of it in vanilla JS: `Math.PI`, `Math.SQRT2`, `Node.TEXT_NODE`.