# How to store enum object in variable Typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I have the following typescript enum:

```js
export enum Textures { 
    earth = "Earth", 
    colors = "Colors", 
    disturb = "Disturb",
    ...,
    many = "More"
}
```

Further I have a GUI where i set my initial texture to show:

```js
export class DefaultSettings {
  texture: Textures = Textures.earth;
  //more Settings
}

let settings = new DefaultSettings();
```

So when i change the value in my GUI, selecting "Colors" I don't want to write my callback for every single entry in the enum. eg:

```js
if(selcted.value == "Colors"){
  settings.texture = Textures.colors;
}
if(selcted.value == "Disturb"){
  settings.texture = Textures.disturb;
}
if(selcted.value == "Earth"){
  settings.texture = Textures.earth;
}

...

if(selcted.value == "More"){
  settings.texture = Textures.many;
}
```

How can I set the `Texture Enum object` into the `settings.texture` attribute? E.G.:

```
settings.texture = Textures.X // This saves the string, but I want the object itself
```

or

```
settings.texture = Textures[X] // wrong since it puts 'string' instead of 'Textures'
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that the type of `selcted.value` will always be the enum value, you can do something like this:

```
settings.texture = selcted.value as Textures
```

Also, I would also recommend to:

- rename `Textures` to `Texture` as naming convention recommend using singular names for `enum` [[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233137/javascript-enum-pattern-naming-convention)]
- change your enum key to `ALL_CAPS` or `Capital` format
- check with `===` instead of `==` [[eslint eqeqeq](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/eqeqeq)]
- rename `selcted` to `selected`

Comment: If you aren't sure that the value will always be a texture, you can check it against the values of the enum: `const isTexture = (value: string): value is Textures => (Object.values(Textures) as string[]).includes(value);`